# How to solve a nonhomogeneous Cauchy-Euler equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For this question, I'm not sure how to solve the non-homogeneous Cauchy-Euler equation. Here is what I have so far. I'm not sure how to continue. Can anyone please help me out?

$t^2 u''-2u = t^3$

$u''-\frac{2u}{t^2} = t$

Let $ u = t^m$

$u' = mt^{m-1}$

$u'' = m(m-1)t^{m-2}$

$ m(m-1)t^{m-2} - \frac{2t^m}{t^2} = t$

$ t^{m-2} (m(m-1)-2) = t$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$t^2 u''-2u = t^3$$
$$t^2 u''+2tu'-2tu'-2u = t^3$$
$$(t^2u')'-2(tu)'=t^3$$
$$(t^2u'-2tu)'=t^3$$
$$\left(t^4 \left(\dfrac u {t^2}\right)'\right)'=t^3$$
Integrate.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the answer now, thanks

Comment: That's great ...@user6789

Answer (score 0):

You first solve the homogeneous equation using the characteristic polynomial $0=m^2-m-2=(m-2)(m+1)$. As the homogeneous basis is $t^{-1}, t^2$, the right side is not in resonance and the method of undetermined coefficients gives a particular solution in the form $y=At^3$.